# Tools to lock/encrypt folder in debian

Tags: debian, directory, encryption

Is there any tools to encrypt folder except encfs for debian?

Comment: What is wrong or the issue with encfs? That may help with an answer.

Comment: is it the effective way to lock the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cryptsetup](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) can be used;

```
MOUNT_NAME=example
cryptsetup luksOpen /path/to/file "$MOUNT_NAME"
mount "/dev/mapper/$MOUNT_NAME" /path/to/mount
```

encfs encrypts per file

- disadvantage: attackers know your file sizes, layout, modification time etc.
- advantage: no need to grow or shrink your container

cryptsetup encrypts per mount point

- disadvantage: one needs to manage the container size
- advantage: 100% encrypted... and some technical stuff about roiling ciphers

Comment: encfs also do the same like cryptsetup I guess?